# Specify user input date format in WPF datepicker

Tags: wpf

I would like users to have an ability to type in dates in datepicker control. The two formats allowed are MMDDYYYY or MMDDYY, by default it is not possible to do it without slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish that easily with telerik's RadDatePicker. Setting  AllowParsingWithoutSeparator="True" property resolved my issue. The other solution is to have a textbox with mask.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with this myself. Decided I wanted more of a "maskedtextbox" serving as my textbox versus the datepickertextbox. I had to include WPFToolkit for the maskedtextbox control. Then, I created a new class that inherits from Datepicker and added a few dependencyproperties. From there I created a resourcedictionary for the XAML of how to display this new custom date picker. You can build You'll lose the watermark but you gain a mask which I think is more user friendly.

You won't be able to accomplish what you are looking for without a custom control since Datepicker is tightly synced together where the selected Calendar date is an actual date and SelectedDate has to also be a date and the format MMDDYYYY isn't considered a date.

Comment: Thanks Dusting for ponting it out. I upvoted your very useful answer, good tip, another way of doing it. I managed to resolve my issue easily with telerik's RadDatePicker